# Perl/Ruby one-liner array manipulation

Tags: ruby, perl

Hello I am trying to make a one-liner in perl( or ruby ) that reads data from a file into an array, and prints it in columns with a newline after ever 10nth element.

The file is like this

```
Name
Course1
Mark1
Course2
Mark2
Course3
Mark3
Course4
Mark4
```

And should be displayed like this

```
Name   Course1  Mark1   Course2   Mark2   Course3   Mark3   Course4   Mark4
```

This is what I have tried to far

```
perl -ne '@a=split"\n",$_;print join("\t"=>splice@a,0,10)' Data.txt
```

Comment: in the output how are the columns separated; with tab ?

Comment: yes, they are separated by tabs

Comment: You said "after every 10th element", but your example only has 9. 9 or 10?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That doesn't work because you're splitting on newlines when you read a line at a time. You'd need `-0777` to make it work.

You also only print the first 10 elements, so you'd need to introduce a loop.

```
perl -0777nE'@F = split /\n/; say join "\t", splice @F,0,10 while @F' Data.txt
```

That begs to take advantage of `-a`!

```
perl -F'\n' -0777naE'say join "\t", splice @F,0,10 while @F' Data.txt
```

---

Or we can take a completely different approach. Short and sweet:

```
perl -pe's/\n/\t/ if $. % 10' Data.txt
```

If there isn't a multiple of 10 columns, that will end with a trailing tab instead of a newline. Ok, not so good. Then how about

```
perl -0777pe's/\n(?!\z)/ ++$i % 10 ? "\t" : "\n" /eg' Data.txt
```

---

**Update** You've since changed your question to request fixed-width fields.

If you know the width in advance (say 10 + 2 chars between fields = 12):

```
perl -F'\n' -0777naE'say pack "(A12)9 A*", splice @F,0,10 while @F' Data.txt
```

If you don't:

```
perl -MList::Util=max -F'\n' -0777naE'
   $w = 2 + max map length, @F;
   say pack "(A$w)9 A*", splice @F,0,10 while @F;
' Data.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much that worked :). Now to add on to it, would it be possible to use "field sizes" to make the columns align nicely?

Comment: @user1976336, You said you wanted to use tabs. If you want fixed-width fields, it's a completely different question!

Answer (score 2):

```
ruby -e 'ARGF.map{|l|l.strip}.each_slice(10) {|a| puts a.join "\t"}' Data.txt
```

Comment: It'd help the OP if you *explained* what the code is doing. Don't give people fish, teach them HOW to fish.

Answer (score 0):

ikegami beat me to it. But I'll post mine anyways.

```
perl -pe 'tr/\n/\t/ if $. % 9 != 0'
```

EDIT:
Ah, even better. Thanks ikegami( for the `$.`, I forgot about that one).

Answer (score 0):

The data sample is only nine lines, so it won't fit conveniently into a ten-line bucket. I added a placeholder so my text file looks like:

```
Name
Course1
Mark1
Course2
Mark2
Course3
Mark3
Course4
Mark4
-----
Name
Course1
Mark1
Course2
Mark2
Course3
Mark3
Course4
Mark4
-----
```

I'd do it in Ruby something along these lines:

```
puts ARGF.lines.map(&:chomp).each_slice(10).map{ |a| a.join(' ') }
```

Which gives me an output like:

```
Name Course1 Mark1 Course2 Mark2 Course3 Mark3 Course4 Mark4 -----
Name Course1 Mark1 Course2 Mark2 Course3 Mark3 Course4 Mark4 -----
```

Using tabs instead of spaces is trivial: replace `' '` with `"\t"`, but how is left as an exercise for the reader.

`map(&:chomp)` strips the trailing line-endings so the fields can exist on one line when printed. `each_slice(10)` grabs array elements ten at a time, which results in an array-of-arrays, each sub-array containing ten strings. The final `map{ |a| a.join(' ') }` joins the sub-arrays with spaces, or tabs if changed to `"\t"`. Alternately, `a * ' '` or `a * "\t"` could have been used instead of `join`, but `join` is more commonly used.